# PL/SQL Function Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question to the following Pl/SQL block:

I want to check if the username is in the table.
IF that is true, an exception should be raised.

```
declare
BEREITS_VORHANDEN EXCEPTION;
begin
IF (select username from benutzer where username=:P12_USERNAME) IS NOT NULL THEN
raise BEREITS_VORHANDEN;
END IF;
end;

ERROR:
ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null 

   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date 
   pipe
```

Comment: Sorry couldn't help you more. Check this link http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=319710

Comment: tanks for your estimate. 
I solved it:

declare
tempu number;
BEREITS_VORHANDEN EXCEPTION;
begin
select COUNT(*) into tempu from BENUTZER where username=:P12_USERNAME;
IF tempu > 0 THEN
raise BEREITS_VORHANDEN;
END IF;
end;

Comment: Make select count(*) with rownum < 2 then check that count

Answer (score 0):

This functions behaves as you want it to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_user_name_stuff(_P12_USERNAME varchar) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  user_name_not_found boolean;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) = 0 INTO user_name_not_found
  FROM benutzer
  WHERE username=_P12_USERNAME;

  IF (user_name_not_found) THEN
    raise EXCEPTION 'BEREITS_VORHANDEN'; 
  END IF; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I wouldn't do it this way unless the missing username is an exceptional case, i.e. you really expect it to be there. Just use a boolean function. Furthermore, try not to nest function calls inside conidtional statements, it makes an already too verbose langauge even less readable.

Enjoy! :)